# Xamarin.Forms equivalent to overriding iOS's SendEvent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on inactivity detection.

I have successfully done so in iOS by subclassing `UIApplication` and overriding `SendEvent` as outlined [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222102620/http://www.pranavkhandelwal.com/blog/2015/11/1/detecting-user-inactivityidle-time-for-xamarinios).

I know I could implement this separately for both iOS and Android, but I'd rather have a cross-platform Forms approach by intercepting all touch events and resetting my timers. I'd rather not have to add a touch event handler to all my pages either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find a cross platform approach. I was able to accomplish this by leaving the timer related information in core Forms project and implement the touch event handlers separately for iOS and Android. I handled the iOS touch events as outlined in the link in the OP, but for Android I took the approach of subclassing `Activity` due to the presence of the `OnUserInteraction()` method.

Initially I thought I would have to force Xamarin to use my subclassed `Activity` for all pages that I use in Xamarin, but I was mistaken. AdamMeaney over on the Xamarin forums was able to help with providing a solution for the Android side of things with regards to subclassing an Android activity. As it turns out, Xamarin only uses one `Activity` which inherits from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity`. I used the `MainAcitivty` provided by Xamarin in the Droid project. From there, overriding the `OnUserInteraction()` proved to be quite simple:

```
public override void OnUserInteraction()
{
    base.OnUserInteraction();
    //Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that all you really have to do on the platform side is get notified whenever a new touch event occurs. Unless I am missing something it seems you can do all of the timer stuff in the PCL core Forms project and call that code from the platform specific code that runs when a touch is detected.

So if on Android ( I did not verify, but I would assume so) there is a similar way to handle any touch, device wide, then it would seem that all you have to do is implement that event handler, as you did for iOS, and call into your Forms core code to handle the timer(s).

To clarify: On the platform side, just handle the touch events globally and then call into code in the Forms core thus only having to implement the timer functionality once. Or so it would seem unless I am missing something.

If you want to make a feature request for Xamarin Form, please do so at Xamarin's user voice page: xamarin.uservoice.com

I suspect Forms would just have to do as outlined above... handle device wide touches on each platform and then have a virtual method in Forms core code that is called whenever a touch occurs.

Comment: Yes, that is the approach I will be taking should I have to do so. I was hoping there would be a method I could override within Forms that handles touch events for all platforms rather than having to jump into the platform specific touch event handlers.

Comment: @TimothyJames I have stumbled upon your post and I would like to know if in the end you made it work for Android and willing to share a sample code. I have done something using prism I cannot navigate to the page when the timer has elapsed.Grateful for your input since you went through this already

Comment: @developer9969 Does my answer below not help?

Comment: @TimothyJames you mentioned "answer below" I suppose you meant the answer above. I cannot see any implementation for  android. Also for iOS i will try to make your snippets work.Do you have a full sample on github? Are you aware of a cross platform solution for this? Really appreciate your suggestions

Comment: @developer9969 It's below on my machine. You're right that there is no implementation for Android because all I did was override `OnUserInteraction` in the Android `MainActivity` class. Why don't you ask a question and link it to me and I'll do my best to answer it.