# login expiration/idle timeout for mobile apps

Tags: authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I am new to Xamarin and getting started on building an app. I am using XAMARIN.Auth to store the user name and the Token after login. 
The Auth token on the server has expiration. When the user resumes the app from the background, what is the best practice to see if they need to login or use the existing token? I am thinking of checking the token validation from service. Is that ok? And how is idle timeout implemented?

Comment: From the service it's should be okay. Also,you can add some logic to lifecycle methods(onRestart/OnStart/OnPause).

Answer (score 0):

In your App.xaml.cs, you will find your OnResume, OnStart, OnSleep methods. You can override those methods to do what you would like.

For creating idle timeout, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515886/xamarin-forms-equivalent-to-overriding-ioss-sendevent). It will involve creating a public class library that is called by overriding iOS's `SendEvent` and creating a subclass for Android's `Activity`.