# What is the equvalent of "OnUserInteraction" in iOS

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to know if there is any android "OnUserInteraction" equvalent in iOS. I want to implement session logout functionality so I need to know any equvalent functionality fo OnUserInteraction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515886/xamarin-forms-equivalent-to-overriding-ioss-sendevent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms equivalent to overriding iOS's SendEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515886/xamarin-forms-equivalent-to-overriding-ioss-sendevent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS you can subclass `UIApplication` and override `SendEvent` as outlined [here](http://www.pranavkhandelwal.com/blog/2015/11/1/detecting-user-inactivityidle-time-for-xamarinios).